# how to publish png artifacts in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to publish artifacts in my jenkin after a successful build.
My code structure is somewhat:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'make'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'make test'
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried

```
stage('Build') {
    
}

stage('Test') {
    
}

stage('Archive Artifacts') {
    archive includes: '/*.png'
}
```

but this not working for me.

Comment: update the code "archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.png', allowEmptyArchive: true"

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            // build your project here
        }
        stage('Test') {
            // run tests here
        }
        stage('Archive Artifacts') {
            steps {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.jar,logs/*.log', excludes: 'target/**/*'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we're archiving all JAR files and log files in the logs directory, but excluding anything in the target directory

Answer (score 1):

Updated code **'allowEmptyArchive'** parameter allows the artifacts to be archived even if there is no matching file.

```
pipeline 
    {
    agent any 
    stages 
    {
    stage ('Build')
    {
    steps {
    sh 'make'
    }
    }
    stage ('Test')
    {
    steps {
    sh 'make'
    }
    }
    stage ('Archive Artifacts')
    {
    steps 
    {
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.png', allowEmptyArchive: true  
    }
    }
    }
    }
```